# Moodle not sending emails

Tags: email, moodle

We have our site hosted on managed server , as example I will use the name `moodlesite.com`. 
Under

`moodlesite.com/admin/settings.php?section=messagesettingemail`

we changed the 
`No-reply address` from  `noreply@moodlesite.com` to `organisation@someothersite.com`, choose the checkbox under it for `Always send email from the no-reply address?` and saved it.

Here the problem was, that we didn't set the SMTP-settings for the new email address, I presume?

The site stopped sending emails to the self registered users, or any emails.

Reversing the change- unchecking the box and setting our default `noreply@moodlesite.com` address didn't helped and sending emails is still not working.

Reproducing the same on our company server it did the same and the emailing functions of the site stopped working,even after reversing the changes. But after an hour it worked normally again.

Do we have to contact our hosting provider and ask for the SMTP settings for `noreply@moodlesite.com`, or as the email has the same domain as our site, it should work without setting them?

Or just uncheck everything and use

```
moodlesite.com/admin/settings.php?section=supportcontact
```

Comment: The issue was resolved, after we uncommented the `php_openssl.dll` extension in `php.ini`

Comment: I think that's probably a side effect - I would imagine commenting that line out would have other impacts as well. All it's done to resolve the issue is stop your system from trying to connect to the mail server using SSL.  Is it possible you accidentally set the "SMTP security" value as well when you made the original change?

Comment: For anyone reading this in future, before considering the above solution, please ensure that you have an email address created for your domain, Then simply set up Moodle to send emails via that address (Site admin -> Server -> then email set up (from my memory but i could be wrong). It was quite simple once I found the answer. Hope this helps.